# why am I getting different result for same query in neo4j browser and javascript driver

Tags: neo4j, cypher, nestjs

I have the following query:

```
 MATCH(c:Member)-[:ISA_CANDIDATE]->(r:Race)-[rr:OF_ELECTION]->(e:Elections {election_id: "2be432d6-1e72-490c-9318-f75d7d3b68c3"})
RETURN {race_rank: r.rank, race_name: r.name, race_id: r.race_id, candidates: {candidates_name: c.first_name+
 ' '+c.middle_name+' '+c.last_name, candidate_id: c.member_id, picture: c.picture}} ORDER BY r.rank ASC
```

both in neo4j browser (4.4.50 and nestjs driver (nest-neo4j 0.1.5). I am getting the expected results in the browser but null in the driver....I have a suspicion that my nested object return statement might be the culprit! so the question why the different results and how can I get the desired result I need?

Answer (score 0):

When you execute the query from the driver, you need to read the value from the record, subscribing to the results.
These are the functions you can call to get result, error and close connection.

```
const session = driver.session({
  database: 'yourDatabase',
});
session
  .run(
    `ReplaceQUERY -MATCH(c:User)-[:IS_PART_OF]->(r:Project {id: "b18e0f1b-ef98-478e-af44-de17573a0cfa"}) RETURN {race_rank: r.name, race_name: r.client, race_id: r.id, candidates: {candidates_name: c.firstName+' '+c.lastName, candidate_id: c.id}} ORDER BY c.id ASC`,
  )
  .subscribe({
    onKeys: (keys) => {
      console.log(keys);
    },
    onNext: (record) => {
      console.log(record); // you result object
    },
    onCompleted: () => {
      session.close(); // returns a Promise / Close connection
    },
    onError: (error) => {
      console.log(error); // Read Error
    },
  });
```

I hope it helps you
Cheers

Comment: @tektro welcome and thanks fro taking the time to look at my question. I am actually doing what you suggested....I think thats the only way to get the data. the null or undefined result is coming from results.records[0]. Sorry I wasn't clear.

Comment: The DB was apparently corrupted.....cleaned it and now I am good.